# Polling a button and delaying/switching based on the input. Millis? Delay and loop counter?

Tags: programming, delay, state-machines, c++

So this is the setup:

[image]

I previously asked a question about this assignment. THIS IS A NEW QUESTION.
THIS IS NEW CODE. ONLY THE IMAGES ARE THE SAME.

I originally approached this using an interrupt on the button, which flipped between two different states depending on the buttonFlag... This is close to what I want, but on that question it was suggested to design it as a "state-machine" and to just poll the button at regular intervals, since the interrupt wasn't necessary.

What I can't get my head around is the program flow, I'm using a switch statement now, and if, for example it was 1 second on, 1 second delay, this version below is close. But I need to figure out how write an LED state and hold it for a set period, AND poll the button in between, without an interrupt.

The various wait times (and program flow within the switch) are the main issue for me now... poll the switch and use millis to set the delay between state changes?... use delay and simply count all the waits in terms of loop iterations?

[image]

I'm very very stumped at this point, but very interested in learning to use switch statements this way seems like a useful skill to have in the toolkit.

Thanks for reading and for any thoughts/feedback.

```
// traffic light controller.
#define green1 3
#define orange1 4
#define red1 5
#define green2 6
#define orange2 7
#define red2 8
#define green3 9
#define red3 10
#define crossingButton 2

//global variables
int toggleState;
int lastButtonState = 1;
long unsigned int currentTime; 
long unsigned int waitTime; 
int debounceTime = 10;
int i = 0; // display state pointer.
uint8_t buttonFlag = digitalRead(crossingButton);
int systemState = 1;
int old; 

//BCD traffic lights states. I did this so I can use the i in displayState[i]
// as a pointer to different system states
int displayState[] =  {133, 69, 37, 49, 41, 37, 50, 42, 37};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //setup pin modes
  pinMode(green1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(orange1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(orange2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(crossingButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (systemState < 6 && !buttonFlag && (((millis())-currentTime) > waitTime)) {
    ++systemState;
    Serial.println(" in here now");
    //Serial.println("systemState is " + systemState);
  }
  else if (buttonFlag) {
    systemState = 7;
  }

  switch (systemState) {

  case 1: // GRR 
    i = 0; 
    showLights();
    Serial.println(" buttonflag is " + buttonFlag);
    Serial.println(" systemState is 1");
    //delay(1000);
    currentTime = millis();
    waitTime = 5000;
    old = systemState;
    break;
  case 2:
    Serial.println(" systemState is 2");
    i = 1; 
    showLights();
    delay(1000);
    old = systemState;
    break;
  case 3:
    Serial.println(" systemState is 3");
    old = systemState;
    break;
  case 4:
    Serial.println(" systemState is 4");
    break;
  case 5:
    break;
  case 6:
    break;
  case 7:
    break;
  }
} //end main loop

void showLights() {
  digitalWrite(green1, (bitRead(displayState[i],7)));
  digitalWrite(orange1, (bitRead(displayState[i],6)));
  digitalWrite(red1, (bitRead(displayState[i],5)));
  digitalWrite(green2, (bitRead(displayState[i],4)));
  digitalWrite(orange2, (bitRead(displayState[i],3)));
  digitalWrite(red2, (bitRead(displayState[i],2)));
  digitalWrite(green3, (bitRead(displayState[i],1)));
  digitalWrite(red3, (bitRead(displayState[i],0)));
}
```

Comment: So why did you delete the previous question from few houra ago, why did you not edit it? Besides there is no single best way of doing this, there's got to be dozens of ways and if they do the job correctly then any of them is good. If you make a too elegant version, such as going to sleep for LED wait period unless button interrupt wakes the AVR from sleep, your supervisor may become suspicious.

Comment: I would probably record the LED's turn-on time when you set the output high, set a boolean at the same time, and poll the switch to set a second boolean.  I would also consider using a push-on push-off switch instead of a momentary so you avoid any (unlikely) issues with a rapid switch press getting lost while your code is doing something else.

Comment: this is C++: for constants, you should *not* use `#define`, but simply a `constexpr` (or just  a `const`) `int green = 7;`, for example. In fact, however, this is *the* use case for a `enum` in both C and C++!

Comment: same, and even more so, because this is quite literally the finite state machine use case `enum`s were invented for, your `system_state` should be an `enum` with descriptive names. Note that all this does not at all reduce the speed or increase the size of your machine code - it just makes your C++ safer to write!

Comment: `i` should **not* be a global variable, but definitely just an argument to `showLights`. Generally, none of these global variables should be global, but local to `loop`. None of them aside from `state` should be `static` even!

Comment: remove `old`. It's unused and quite confusing.

Comment: `ì` takes exactly two values, `0` or `1`: Why does `displayState` have 9 entries? all but the first two are never going to be accessed.  Aside from your code not being acceptable as good C++ code (you really need to learn about scope, and how functions deal with parameters!) , this points to a deeper logical flaw in your whole program, and I can't even guess what your intention there was.

Comment: Also, certain LEDs are lit until either time is up or button push seen so state machine should enter next state. What does it matter if you run the state machine 1000 times per second according to elapsed millisecond timer, or 123456 times per second according to some while loop?

Comment: Jesus... I feel like I'm on trial anytime I do anything on this site. I deleted the previous question because it was downvoted and (wrongly) reported for being the same question by one of the homework police... I did edit it, but I didn't think anyone would answer it. 

Rest assured guys the broad hostility and "why can't you ask a perfect question about a subject you don't understand?" vibes are beyond intolerable. This will be my last 
visit to this site. 

Thanks for anyone attempting to help.

Comment: Just one other thing, Marcus... I'm a beginner. displayState is an array of BCD values (it's in the code and it's commented as such). 

My question actually explains why there are unused variables. I will 
clear them when I know what I'm using and what I amn't... this bit relates to my question. 

Thanks for the broad code review, congratulations for telling a beginner their code isn't good... profound insight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the common mistake of writing code to solve a problem you don't fully understand. The outcome is you usually run around in circles.

You need to break the problem down into bite size chunks that are easy to solve.

Firstly, you need to create a state diagram. Give each state a descriptive name eg: MAIN_STOP,MAIN_CAUTION,MAIN_GO. The system can only exist in one state at one time, so when there is MAIN_GO the secondary lights are STOP by implication. Once you've defined your system states, then determine the transitions - the inputs that cause a change from one state to another. This could be elapsed time or an input. You might find you need some intermediate states like MAIN_STOP_WAIT that will sit in that state until X seconds has elapsed. The key here is states and inputs. Outputs are derived from the states.

A state diagram consists of circles that denote a given state and arrows that show the transition of one state to another. I draw this using a pencil and paper as I'm old-skool. Wikipedia has an example of 'state diagram' and there's a zillion other examples on the 'web.

Once you've refined your state diagram - yes, it is iterative. After your first pass you might observe sequences that can be simplified. Once completed, you should be able to talk yourself through each state. `if in MAIN_STOP AND button pressed then .......`. For a given state and inputs, you should be able to determine what to do next. If you can't, then circle back and refine the state diagram.

Now you can translate the state diagram into some code. You've already solved the logic with the state diagram, so it should be a simple task to write the code. Here's some pseudo code:

(I've got no idea on how to draw a state diagram on this website, so I'll use words). The example sets the main lights to stop, waits 10 seconds then sets the main light to caution, waits 5 seconds then goes back to setting the main lights to stop and so on.

```cpp
switch(state)
{
MAIN_STOP:
   show_main_stop(); // function to set the gpio to activate the main stop light and turn all others off.
   counter = 10 * TICKS_PER_SECOND;
   state = MAIN_STOP_DELAY;
   break;

MAIN_STOP_DELAY:
   if counter > 0 then counter-- else state = MAIN_CAUTION;
   break;

MAIN_CAUTION:
   show_main_caution(); //set the traffic lights to caution on main road
   counter = 5 * TICKS_PER_SECOND; //wait 5 seconds
   state = MAIN_CAUTION_DELAY;
   break;

MAIN_CAUTION_DELAY:
   if counter > 0 then counter-- else state = MAIN_STOP;
   break;
}
```

The idea is that the state machine gets called at regular intervals so we can time things accurately. I suggest 10ms or 100Hz(times per second). This would make TICK_PER_SECOND equal to 100. In C you would:
`#define TICKS_PER_SECOND 100`

Another concept I introduced is writing functions that abstract the traffic lights from the low level gpio. We know there's only certain combinations of lights that make sense on a traffic light. Write functions to enforce this. If you name your functions well, it makes your code easy to read and follow. It also keeps the low level details localised - you really don't want to be twiddling gpio all throughout your code.

To keep track of elapsed time, I down count the ticks. Load the number of ticks you want to delay and at each tick, the count gets decremented. When the count gets to 0, the time required time has elapsed. You could start at 0 and increment each tick then compare for the required time if you want, but I tend to use downcounting.

To create your 10ms ticks, we could simply:

```cpp
loop()
{
    do_state_machine(); 
    delayms(10);
}
```

expanding the example to handle inputs, we might do something like:

```cpp
loop()
{
    debounce_switches();
    do_state_machine();
    delayms(10);
}
```

The idea is to break your code out into functions. The basic rule of a function: do one thing only. The function *debounce_switches()* should do what it says - it won't flash lights or make tea, it will debounce the switches. It might call other functions etc but it should do what is necessary to debounce your switches.

The other issue is how to handle a button press whilst doing something else. I'd suggest you add logic to latch a button press. The state machine can read the latched press then reset it once it has read it.

Your loop code might then look like this:

```cpp
loop()
{
    debounce_switches();
    latch_switches();
    do_state_machine();
    delayms(10);
}
```

I'll leave it here. Hopefully I've led you through the basic steps of designing a solution to your problem.

Further to the comments re responding to button input.

```cpp
switch(state)
{
MAIN_STOP:
   show_main_stop(); // function to set the gpio to activate the main stop light and turn all others off.
   counter = 10 * TICKS_PER_SECOND;
   state = MAIN_STOP_DELAY;
   break;

MAIN_STOP_DELAY:
   if (is_button_latched() == true) then state = CROSSWALK_GO
   else
      {
      if counter > 0 then counter-- else state = MAIN_CAUTION;
      }
   break;

MAIN_CAUTION:
   show_main_caution(); //set the traffic lights to caution on main road
   counter = 5 * TICKS_PER_SECOND; //wait 5 seconds
   state = MAIN_CAUTION_DELAY;
   break;

MAIN_CAUTION_DELAY:
   if counter > 0 then counter-- else state = MAIN_STOP;
   break;

CROSSWALK_GO:
   show_crosswalk_go();
   counter = 30 * TICKS_PER_SECOND; //wait 30 seconds
   state = CROSSWALK_GO_WAIT;
   break;

CROSSWALK_GO_WAIT:
   if counter > 0 then counter-- else state = MAIN_STOP;
   break;
}
```

In terms of a real traffic light you'd want a minimum time for each light state - having a traffic light active for 10ms or even 1 second would give little time for the traffic to respond, so you would need to add states or transition logic to ensure a minimum time.

Just to recap - every 10ms the code will:
read the input switch
run the debounce code
run the latch code
run the state machine code
rinse and repeat.

For the input, the state machine isn't concerned about how it got the input - it calls a function *is_button_latched()* that returns a true or false. Debouncing and latching has been done by the other code, again running every 10ms.

simple debounce example:

````cpp
#define DEBOUNCE_COUNT 5   //switch must be active for 5 consecutive ticks

bool debounce()
{
static int count = 0;
bool pressed = false;

    if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == true)
      {
      if (count > 0)
        {
        count--;
        }
      else
        {
        pressed = true;
        }
      }
    else
      {
      count = DEBOUNCE_COUNT;
      }
    return pressed;
}
```
````

Comment: Thank you for this Kartman. I have looked at state diagrams... I've tried to draw several, and I've some experience with flow charts... both really seemed to ask the question "What decisions am I making here and based on what?" particularly re:timing. Which you just answered. 

I'm a beginner in the world of C++ programming and programming in general. The switch statement isn't something I've used before... I can't visualise or intuit how I structure the cases, but you've definitely answered my question in terms of how you'd
loop and poll the switch. Thank you again. 

Comment: How to structure the cases? I gave an example. What you need to have very clear is the states of your system. With the pedestrian button, at what state or states do you make a decision on that input? I’d guess when the secondary road green has finished, test the latched switch bit. If set then the next state is pedestrian go. Define the legal combinations of the lights - thats your basic states. Then add the delay states. Off the top of my head, thats about 12 states. For the most part it cycles sequentially through 10 states then optionally the pedestrian ones.

Comment: I didn't read or paste that into my IDE properly last time, thank you for the edit. I see what you're saying now.

Comment: "With the pedestrian button, at what state or states do you make a decision on that input? I’d guess when the secondary road green has finished, test the latched switch bit."

I can't wait for the light to finish. Main green is 120 seconds. I need the crosswalk button to work within 10. So if we wait for each state like a single, uninterruptable event, we only know about the crosswalk button AFTER the light has changed.

My thinking is I have to write a state and a wait time in each case, exit the switch and enter a loop that decrements and polls the switch, and makes decisions from there.

Comment: you wrote: exit the switch and enter a loop that decrements and polls the switch, and makes decisions from there.  You could do that, but you've created an exception that should be catered for by the state machine. As per my additions to the answer - the state machine does not concern itself with the actual reading and debouncing etc of the switch. You *could* put debouncing and other things in the state machine function, but that would just make it harder to understand and test. The trick of programming, or indeed problem solving is to divide and conquer. Solve one problem at a time.

Comment: TBH I'm still coming to grips with how elegant this is. It's like having someone spring clean your brain for you. Wow. 

The switch part looks like assembly in the best of ways. You can really visualise the loops and jumps. This has been a masterclass mate thank you so so much especially for the patience, sorry it took me that long to cop on. What a chap. 